# Can we avoid eventual consistency in Cloudant with quorum in the query?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I have a requirement where I need to read the documents immediately after writing to the Cloudant DB. Sometimes the DB returns inconsistent results which is expected. But can we avoid eventual consistency by setting the quorum parameter to a higher value (> 2) in the query?

```
{
  "selector": {
     "year": {
         "$gt": 2010
     }
  },
  "r": 5
}
```

Comment: If you set r == number of nodes, you should be guaranteed to get the most recent version, but then you risk getting _no_ result (other than an error) if any node is unreachable or goes down.  If you have many requests like this, then you'll also risk overloading your servers, and might consider _not_ using a replicated database.

Comment: Usually the best solution is to find a different data access pattern that doesn't depend on reading the latest data. But without knowing your use case, it's impossible to offer solutions (or determine that it's impossible).

Comment: @FlimzyThanks for answering, So we have only 1 use case where we have to read the data immediately after writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

There is no way to "remove" eventual consistency in Cloudant (safely). None. My advice would be to not mess with quorum and replicas other than the default values which are set as they are for very good reasons.

If you find yourself needing to work around eventual consistency, either your workload or your data model is unsuited for Cloudant.

Here's a good intro (disclaimer: I'm the author) https://blog.cloudant.com/2019/11/21/Best-and-Worst-Practices.html